# Flutter assets_audio_player keep playing multiple audios if instance is not disposed

Tags: flutter, dart, assets

I am using flutter assets_audio_player package and it has a bug. It is playing multiple audios instead of replacing the existing audio. I tried many ways to stop and play in the initState() method but didn't work. I dont want to dispose it because I want to be able to navigate to other screens while playing audio in the background.

> If I dont dispose the audio instance it plays fine in the background but when I go back to load the same audio again it doesn't stop the audio playing already instead it starts playing multiple audios.

```
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AudioPlayer6Page extends StatefulWidget {
  const AudioPlayer6Page({super.key});

  @override
  State<AudioPlayer6Page> createState() => _AudioPlayer6PageState();
}

class _AudioPlayer6PageState extends State<AudioPlayer6Page> {
  late AssetsAudioPlayer assetsAudioPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer();
    loadMedia();
  }

  Future<void> loadMedia() async {
    try {
      await assetsAudioPlayer.open(
          Audio.network(
              "https://s3.amazonaws.com/scifri-episodes/scifri20181123-episode.mp3"),
          autoStart: false,
          showNotification: true);
    } catch (t) {
      //mp3 unreachable
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();

    print('dispose');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text('Another audio player'),
                ),
                StreamBuilder(
                    stream: assetsAudioPlayer.isPlaying,
                    builder: (context, asyncSnapshot) {
                      final bool? isPlaying = asyncSnapshot.data;
                      return isPlaying == true
                          ? Center(
                              child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    assetsAudioPlayer.pause();
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.pause,
                                    size: 50,
                                  )))
                          : Center(
                              child: IconButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    assetsAudioPlayer.play();
                                  },
                                  icon: Icon(
                                    Icons.play_arrow,
                                    size: 50,
                                  )),
                            );
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used assets_audio_player, but I recommend https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service for playing audio in the background.